# Jquery ShapeShift: Get element selected during drag before drop?

Tags: jquery, drag, jquery-ui-draggable, shapeshift

I'm using lib jquery shapeshift to drag&drop. I'm using websocket to realtime. When user dragging member, other user cannot drag that member. So I want get element selected during drag before drop. I read document but could not find solution:
https://github.com/AshesOfOwls/jquery.shapeshift/wiki/2.0-api-documentation

I tried event ss-arranged, but it only gets the parent element of the selected element..  Is the library unable to do that?

I tried the code below, but it won't work when I drag the item from one box to another the first time. From the second time it works. Seems like it conflicts something with the library ??

```
$(".item").draggable ({
        drag: function (event, ui) {
            console.log($(this));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution:

```
$( ".item" ).on( "drag", function( event, ui ) {
        console.log($(this));
    } );
```